# Accumulator fails on cluster, works locally

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

In the official spark documentation, there is an example for an accumulator which is used in a `foreach` call which is directly on an RDD:

```
scala> val accum = sc.accumulator(0)
accum: spark.Accumulator[Int] = 0

scala> sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum += x)
...
10/09/29 18:41:08 INFO SparkContext: Tasks finished in 0.317106 s

scala> accum.value
res2: Int = 10
```

I implemented my own accumulator:

```
val myCounter = sc.accumulator(0)

val myRDD = sc.textFile(inputpath) // :spark.RDD[String]

myRDD.flatMap(line => foo(line)) // line 69

def foo(line: String) = {
   myCounter += 1  // line 82 throwing NullPointerException
   // compute something on the input
}
println(myCounter.value)
```

In a local setting, this works just fine. However, if I run this job on a spark standalone cluster with several machines, the workers throw a

```
13/07/22 21:56:09 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task ID 247
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyClass$.foo(MyClass.scala:82)
    at MyClass$$anonfun$2.apply(MyClass.scala:67)
    at MyClass$$anonfun$2.apply(MyClass.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:400)
    at spark.PairRDDFunctions.writeToFile$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:630)
    at spark.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:640)
    at spark.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:640)
    at spark.scheduler.ResultTask.run(ResultTask.scala:77)
    at spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

at the line which increments the accumulator `myCounter`.

My question is: Can accumulators only be used in "top-level" anonymous functions which are applied directly to RDDs and not in nested functions?
If yes, why does my call succeed locally and fail on a cluster?

**edit**: increased verbosity of exception.

Comment: Could you post more of the worker's traceback?

Comment: Have you tried `sc.broadcast(myCounter)`?

Comment: Doesn't `broadcast` return a read-only value? From the [official API docs](http://spark-project.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#spark.SparkContext): "Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a Broadcast object for reading it in distributed functions. The variable will be sent to each cluster only once."

Comment: Good point. Regardless, it looks like spark isn't sending your accumulator to the cluster, hence the null pointer. Not sure how to work around that except change your algorithm around a bit.

Comment: You shouldn't use sc.broadcast() with accumulators.

Comment: @ptikobj: I tried running (essentially) this code in Spark's local-cluster mode, which the Spark unit tests use to create a multi-process standalone cluster.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce this problem.  What version of Spark are you using?  Can you isolate the problem to a small code sample and post a complete program that will let me reproduce this exception?  Did the traceback contain any other sections (like "caused by: ...")?

Comment: The problem appears to be in your foo method.  What happens there?

Comment: is your code contained an `object` or a `class` ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case too, accumulator was null in closure when I used 'extends App' to create a spark application as shown below

```
    object AccTest extends App {


    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AccTest").setMaster("yarn-client")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
    sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum += x)

    println("count:" + accum.value)

    sc.stop
  }
}
```

I replaced extends App with main() method and it worked in YARN cluster in HDP 2.4

```
object AccTest {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AccTest").setMaster("yarn-client")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

        val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
        sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).foreach(x => accum += x)

        println("count:" + accum.value)

        sc.stop
    }
}
```

worked

Comment: Thanks! This saves my 2 days of debugging. Does anyone know why scala.App does not work here?

Answer (score 1):

What if you define the function like this:

```
def foo(line: String, myc: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Int]) = {
    myc += 1
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
foo(line, myCounter)
```

?

Comment: This seems to be correct, You can pass the accumulator that you created to the method

Answer (score -1):

If you use "flatMap" then "myCounter" will not update because "flatMap" is lazy function. You can use this code:

```
myRDD.foreach(line => foo(line))
def foo(line: String) = {myCounter +=1}
println(myCounter.value)
```